# Being given the contribution_id, how can I update the Contribution?

Tags: civicontribute

I have a lot of Organizations, each with its administrator.

Authenticated users can contribute to those (for membership, participation, or simple donation), via Webforms including a Contribution page where the user can select "pay later".

For safety and ease reasons I don't want those organization administrators to use the Civi Contribution Search UI to update a "pay later" Contribution when they receive a check (Check # and Status). And I am looking for a solution to do that in a monitored way.

One way could be : a Views report can provide him with the Contribution_id number.

But then, what ? For instance, how could I use this contribution_id as a token to open a form to update this payment ?

I am open to any suggestion.

(I run Civi 4.7.16 / Drupal 7.54)
(I tested Views VBO, but unsuccessfully)
(I am not a Programmer)

Comment: I think you need to explain your workflow more thoroughly, like explaining the process of making coffee to a Martian. Eg when you say "user" what do you mean? Logged in, logged out, access CiviCRM back end or not.

Comment: Thank you Pete for your comment : I have edited my question to make it more understandable.

Comment: are you using civicrm entity as well?

Comment: I have CiviCRM_Entity installed, but I don't know how I could use it for this purpose

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how exactly but I am sure there will be guys and girls around that do. But you should be able to link a Webform (with CiviCRM integration - check https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_civicrm) to a View and pass a contribution_id to that form.

Comment: I use Webform_Integration a lot, but the only Contribution fields exposed are Contribution Amount, Contribution page (only for credit-card payments), and Contribution customized data fields. ... but no Contribution_id, nor check payment related field.

Comment: Then the answer is probably going to be that it will not be possible with Webform CiviCRM. Perhaps CiviCRM Entity can help you, but I have no experience with that module.

Comment: I have none either.

Comment: Did you try using the contribution ID in the url? Not sure it has been done before but it could be a simple fix

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you may need to add some new functionality to VBO so that these fields become available to you.

Comment: It would, doubtlessly, be a good solution, but I am not able to do that (very basic programming skills), and I have no funding available. To be honnest, I was also thinking of developping a small Extension based upon the API, but I would be starting from the very bottom. All suggestions are welcome.